# How to cut a string after a number of characters in unix?

Tags: unix, shell, sed, strings

How to delete all characters in one line after point with with sed?

I have a file with multiple lines like this:

- 123456789 3483 98765432 56345
- 985745634 3469 67495735 87654

Now I want to delete all after the first 10 characters. So I only want my output to be:

- 123456789
- 985745634

I was googling for that particular example of sed but didn't find any help in those examples.

Answer (score 7):

Consider using **cut** instead of **sed**:

```
cut -c-10
```

This example extracts 10 first characters from the beginning of the line.